# Is it possible that the highchart legends should not be a part of the svg?

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highchart library for displaying the charts.

It displays the chart as an SVG image. The legend part is also a part of the SVG.

[image]

In the screenshot, please check the `<g class="highcharts-legend"` element. It is a part of the SVG.

Is there any possibility that legends should not be a part of the SVG? It should be outside the SVG as an HTML list.

Maybe there is an option in the highchart configurations but I am missing it?

**Update:**

Using the `useHtml` option, the text of the legend is now outside the SVG, but the color dots are still inside the SVG.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is `useHTML` option for legend, but it will place only text elements outside SVG.

```
legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    ...
}
```

You need to create a custom legend if you want to move it fully outside of SVG.

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rox6dc7a/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML

Comment: This option indeed places the legend text outside the SVG but the color with the legend is still the part of the SVG. I have a screenshot but can't add it in the comment.

Comment: Hi @Ahmad, That's exactly what I described. There is no single option to move legend symbols outside of SVG. The best solution seems to be creating your own custom leged. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/246f3rad/